# Missing Webpack Loader Running Cypress test with React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress

I'm trying to use cypress for integration testing on a React project. However, I'm getting the following error:

> Error: Webpack Compilation Error
> ./node_modules/react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css 1:0
> Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

As the error suggests, I'm using the react-pro-sidebar package.

The first lines of the .css file of the package that is causing the error,

```
> @keyframes swing {
|   0%,
|   30%,
```

I've tried installing the css and scss webpack loader but it still failed.

Here's my webpack.config.js file,

```
const {resolve} = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './md5.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: resolve('./dist'),
    filename: 'md5.min.js',
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: "MD5"
  }
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

The code that triggers the error,

```
import React from 'react';

describe('example to-do app', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000')
    })
    
    it("containsMain",()=>{
        cy.contains(".main")
    })
})
```

The error also happens if I just try to load the page as well.

Comment: Hi/ Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @m4a No, couldn't find a solution. I'm using selenium as a replacement